# Flex container clickable with image on left side and text on right centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The desired result should be:
[image]

I know CSS, except flex & grid - both of them drive me crazy.

I need a flex container with 2 columns, entire container must be clickable. The container have image on left side and text on right side.

```css
.myflex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.myflex-item-left {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  padding: 0;
  flex: 50%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.myflex-item-right {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  padding: 0;
  flex: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
img.imgoxauto {
width: 72px;
height: 72px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myflex-container">
<a href="https://www.example.com/abc">
<div class="myflex-item-left">
<div class="myprod-image"><img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/jPGPiJN.jpg" alt="London"></div>  
<div class="myprod-description">
<h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">London</h5>
</div>
</a>
</div>

<a href="https://www.example.com/xyz">
<div class="myflex-item-right">
<div class="myprod-image"><img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/0MAl65z.jpg"></div>  
<div class="myprod-description">
<h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Chicago</h5>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some problems with your markup in terms of opening and closing  brackets not matching. Apart from these problems you could approach the styling something like this:

```css
.myflex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.myflex-item-left,
.myflex-item-right {
  flex: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}

img.imgoxauto {
  height: 100%;
  width: 74px;
}

.myprod-image {
  height: 74px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.myflex-item-left > a,
.myflex-item-right > a {
  display: flex;
}

.clickable-card {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myflex-container">
  <div class="myflex-item-left">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img
          class="imgoxauto"
          src="https://i.imgur.com/jPGPiJN.jpg"
          alt="London"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">London</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img
          class="imgoxauto"
          src="https://i.imgur.com/jPGPiJN.jpg"
          alt="London"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">London</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img
          class="imgoxauto"
          src="https://i.imgur.com/jPGPiJN.jpg"
          alt="London"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">London</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="myflex-item-right">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img
          class="imgoxauto"
          src="https://i.imgur.com/0MAl65z.jpg"
          alt="Chicago"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Chicago</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img
          class="imgoxauto"
          src="https://i.imgur.com/0MAl65z.jpg"
          alt="Chicago"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Chicago</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img
          class="imgoxauto"
          src="https://i.imgur.com/0MAl65z.jpg"
          alt="Chicago"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Chicago</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the main idea is to give the parent flex container `flex-direction: row` so its children columns are displayed next to each other. Then we want each of these two child columns to have their children (cards) be displayed underneath each other.

**Update**

From testing out the website you linked the text in the card wasn't aligned in the middle so I added:

```
.myflex-item-left > a, .myflex-item-right > a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

h5.texth5.myprod-name {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

The `padding-bottom: 0` is set to counteract default padding value set by `h5` styles.

Comment: Your code works perfectly here. But in any WordPress instance do not work (tested on 3 different instances). 
1. Do not inherit from myflex-container "text-align: center;", to center the text. 
2. WordPress add automatically "auto paragraph" which IS NOT empty, it contains (repeat) the link twice (<a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">    </a>). I do not afford to disable "auto p" globally.
Do you have any clue why doesn't works in WordPress?: https://www.publiciteparis.fr/test-flex.html

Comment: @mariusfv I've tested your link. I've updated my answer and addressed the issue of the card text not being aligned in the middle.

Comment: @ Bas van der Linden - Now h5 text is centered correctly (https://www.publiciteparis.fr/test-flex.html). But now the main problem (which I think is a WordPress bug or Divi theme bug) is that WordPress "auto p" (auto paragraph) DUPLICATE TWICE the "a link" with class "clickable-card" (so not an empty .p like usually) - This make a huge space between cards. See image: https://ibb.co/Hprmrqt . If I disable WordPress to add "auto p" everything works like a charm, but will broken all articles (posts) design. Do you have a clue how to prevent to add auto p?

Comment: I have little experience with wordpress, but [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/#more-information) might be useful. Specifically where it references [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpautop-control/) to disable auto p per post. Sounds like it could apply to your situation.

Comment: Was a theme issue, now everything works like a charm (https://www.publiciteparis.fr/test-flex.html). I've try to made it working on 3 columns your solution (flex grow etc) but no chance. Could you please help me? All code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mariusfv/a1mcs9jd/9/

Comment: I've uncommented two things in your fiddle and it seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/ykp8whxj/.

Comment: continue to show 2 columns, like before, instead of 3 columns. It is possible your initial solution presented here to be displayed in 3 columns instead of 2?

Comment: I think it's better to create a new question for this, since the original question is about having a column on the left and a column on the right. I'm guessing you want to change the number of columns depending on the screen size.

Comment: You have right! The new question is published here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547511/flex-container-with-3-columns-image-on-left-side-content-after-image-centered

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your code, but here's what you can write instead.

In HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="your image source here" alt="alt text" />
    </div>
    <p class="description">Your text goes here</p>
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.container {
    width: *any width you want;
    height: *any height you want;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.container .image-box {
    width: *any width you want;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .image-box img {
    height: 100%;
}

.container .description {
    *Apply any font styling here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want all of the items in a grid container and then the inner items in a flex container like this.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="image-box">
            <img src="image" alt="image" />
        </div>
        <h5 class="description">Text</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="image-box">
            <img src="image" alt="image" />
        </div>
        <h5 class="description">Text</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.image-box {
    flex-basis: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-box img {
    height: 100%;
}

h5.description {
    flex: 1;
}
```