# Flex container with 3 columns: image on left side, content after image centered & entrire container clickable

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need a flex container with 3 columns (9 items in total) for PC devices, entire container must be clickable. The container have image on left side and text on right side.

For mobile devices > CSS `@media` till 800px to be one column.
The challenge is the latest 4 containers to have a different class or ID at containers because I want to display only 5 containers for mobile devices (hide that class to devices till 800px with display:none).

```css
.myflex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.myflex-item-left,
.myflex-item-right {
  flex: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}

img.imgoxauto {
  height: 100%;
  width: 74px;
}

.myprod-image {
  height: 74px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.myflex-item-left>a,
.myflex-item-right>a {
  display: flex;
}

.clickable-card {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.myflex-item-left>a,
.myflex-item-right>a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h5.texth5.myprod-name {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="myflex-container">
  <div class="myflex-item-left">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/GmtzHkT.jpg" alt="London" />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">London</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/jPGPiJN.jpg" alt="London" />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Paris</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/HYZ1Ci5.jpg" alt="London" />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Frankfurt</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="myflex-item-right">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/GmtzHkT.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Chicago</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/0MAl65z.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">New York</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/GLLQ3VQ.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Geneva</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/GmtzHkT.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Chicago</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/0MAl65z.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">New York</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
      <div class="myprod-image">
        <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/GLLQ3VQ.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
      </div>
      <div class="myprod-description">
        <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Geneva</h5>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @George - How to display 3 columns for PC devices instead of 2 columns? (now display 2 columns).

Comment: Use media queries to display 3 columns

Comment: Do you want to show below 3 links to the right?

Comment: It displays in two columns, because you put all your elements into two separate containers, `.myflex-item-left` and `.myflex-item-right`. If you want to be flexible with the amount of columns you display on different devices, then you should stop doing _that_ to begin with.

Comment: I will try and answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove your my-flex item divs and add flex wrap to the container, then you can give your cards a width and change that width with a media query for desktop

```css
.myflex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

img.imgoxauto {
  height: 100%;
  width: 74px;
}

.myprod-image {
  height: 74px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.clickable-card {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);  /* one per column */
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (min-width:800px) {
  .clickable-card {
    width: calc(50% - 20px); /* 2 per column above 800px */
  }
}

@media (min-width:1024px) {
  .clickable-card {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 20px); /* 3 per column above 1024px */
  }
}

h5.texth5.myprod-name {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="myflex-container">
  <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
    <div class="myprod-image">
      <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/GmtzHkT.jpg" alt="London" />
    </div>
    <div class="myprod-description">
      <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">London</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
    <div class="myprod-image">
      <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/jPGPiJN.jpg" alt="London" />
    </div>
    <div class="myprod-description">
      <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Paris</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
    <div class="myprod-image">
      <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/HYZ1Ci5.jpg" alt="London" />
    </div>
    <div class="myprod-description">
      <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Frankfurt</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
    <div class="myprod-image">
      <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/GmtzHkT.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
    </div>
    <div class="myprod-description">
      <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Chicago</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
    <div class="myprod-image">
      <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/0MAl65z.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
    </div>
    <div class="myprod-description">
      <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">New York</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
    <div class="myprod-image">
      <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/GLLQ3VQ.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
    </div>
    <div class="myprod-description">
      <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Geneva</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
    <div class="myprod-image">
      <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/GmtzHkT.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
    </div>
    <div class="myprod-description">
      <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Chicago</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
    <div class="myprod-image">
      <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/0MAl65z.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
    </div>
    <div class="myprod-description">
      <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">New York</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
    <div class="myprod-image">
      <img class="imgoxauto" src="https://i.imgur.com/GLLQ3VQ.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
    </div>
    <div class="myprod-description">
      <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Geneva</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you.

```css
.myflex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.myflex-item-left,
.myflex-item-right {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}

img.imgoxauto {
  height: 100%;
  width: 74px;
}

.myprod-image {
  height: 74px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


.clickable-card {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.myflex-item-left > a, .myflex-item-right > a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

h5.texth5.myprod-name {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
.myflex-item-left {
  width: 33%;
  margin: 10px;
}
.myflex-item-right {
  width: 66%;
  margin: 10px;
}
.right-child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}
.right-child a:first-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="myflex-container">
    <div class="myflex-item-left">
        <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
        <div class="myprod-image">
            <img
            class="imgoxauto"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/GmtzHkT.jpg"
            alt="London"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="myprod-description">
            <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">London</h5>
        </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
        <div class="myprod-image">
            <img
            class="imgoxauto"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/jPGPiJN.jpg"
            alt="London"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="myprod-description">
            <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Paris</h5>
        </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.example.com/abc" class="clickable-card">
        <div class="myprod-image">
            <img
            class="imgoxauto"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/HYZ1Ci5.jpg"
            alt="London"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="myprod-description">
            <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Frankfurt</h5>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="myflex-item-right">
        <div class="right-child">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
                <div class="myprod-image">
                    <img
                    class="imgoxauto"
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/GmtzHkT.jpg"
                    alt="Chicago"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="myprod-description">
                    <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Chicago</h5>
                </div>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
                <div class="myprod-image">
                    <img
                    class="imgoxauto"
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/0MAl65z.jpg"
                    alt="Chicago"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="myprod-description">
                    <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">New York</h5>
                </div>
                </a>
        </div>
        <div class="right-child">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
                <div class="myprod-image">
                <img
                    class="imgoxauto"
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/GLLQ3VQ.jpg"
                    alt="Chicago"
                />
                </div>
                <div class="myprod-description">
                <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Geneva</h5>
                </div>
            </a>
        <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
            <div class="myprod-image">
            <img
                class="imgoxauto"
                src="https://i.imgur.com/GmtzHkT.jpg"
                alt="Chicago"
            />
            </div>
            <div class="myprod-description">
            <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Chicago</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="right-child">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
                <div class="myprod-image">
                <img
                    class="imgoxauto"
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/0MAl65z.jpg"
                    alt="Chicago"
                />
                </div>
                <div class="myprod-description">
                <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">New York</h5>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.example.com/xyz" class="clickable-card">
                <div class="myprod-image">
                <img
                    class="imgoxauto"
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/GLLQ3VQ.jpg"
                    alt="Chicago"
                />
                </div>
                <div class="myprod-description">
                <h5 class="texth5 myprod-name">Geneva</h5>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    
    </div>
</div>
```